# split first from rest of list using regex substitution

Tags: regex, perl, split, substitution

I need to split a list between its first item and the rest of its items using regex substitution only.

The lists of items are input as strings using '##' as a separator, e.g.:

```
''
'one'
'one##two'
'one##two##three'
'one##two words##three'
```

My Perl attempt doesn't really work:

```
my $sampleText = 'one##two words##three';
my $first = $sampleText;
my $rest = $sampleText;
$first =~ s/(.+?)(##.*)?/$1/g;
$rest =~ s/(.?+)(##)?(.*)/$3/g;
print "sampleText = '$sampleText', first = '$first', rest = '$rest'\n";

sampleText = 'one##two words##three', first = 'one', rest = 'ne##two words##three'
```

Please note the constraints:

- the separator is a multi-character string
- only regex substitutions are allowed (1)
- I could "chain" regex substitutions if necessary
- The expected end result is two strings: the first element, and the initial string with the first element cut off (2)
- the list may have from 0 to n items, each being any string not containing the separator.

(1) I work with this rather large Perl system where at some point lists of items are processed using provided operations. One of them is a regex substitution. None of the others one are applicable. Solving the problem using full Perl code is easy, but that would mean modifying the system, which is not an option as this time.

(2) the context is the Unimarc bibliographic format, where authors of a publication are to be split into the standard Unimarc fields 700$a for the first author, and 701$a for any remaining authors.

Comment: `only regex substitutions are allowed` Sounds like homework to me. What possible system could not handle using a better tool?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume point (1) means you cannot use the `split` builtin? It would be easy using splits optional third parameter which lets you specify the maximum number of items.

```
my( $first, $rest ) = split( '##', $sampleText, 2 );
```

But if it has to be regex replace then your is almost right, but using `.+?` wont work when there's no sperators (because it will just take the first character You can fix this by anchoring the end. Instead something like:

```
my $sampleText = 'one##two words##three';
my $first = $sampleText;
my $rest = $sampleText;
$first =~ s/(.+?)(|##(.*))$/$1/g;
$rest  =~ s/(.+?)(|##(.*))$/$3/g;
print "sampleText = '$sampleText', first = '$first', rest = '$rest'\n";
```

Comment: Thanks that looks good. You are correct: I don't have the option to use `split`. I'll study your regex to learn how they work (esp this pipe character).

Answer (score 3):

Whatever is the matter with :

```
my ( $first, $rest ) = split /##/, $sampleText, 2;
```

?

Comment: +1 That's my question as well. If you can add a regex and assignments, there seems to be no logical reasons you can't add other code. It appears to be a case of [The Wrong Question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/45154/what-is-a-better-way-to-name-the-wrong-question).

Comment: @TLP : A case of 'The Wrong Question' or not enough information to go by. From the context provided by the OP, it seems like there is nothing wrong with using `split` at all. It would be interesting to understand exactly what restriction is causing the OP to avoid using something as straightforward and error-proof as `split`

Comment: I have no option to add an assignment. I only  have the option to provide 2 pieces of data: a matching pattern and a replacement pattern. As I wrote, my Perl snippet is only conceptually what the system is doing.

Comment: I wrote "Solving the problem using full Perl code is easy, but that would mean modifying the system, which is not an option as this time." Isn't that an answer to your interrogation?

Comment: @Jean-DenisMuys No, it isn't. You'd be surprised how often people ask [The Wrong Question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/45154/what-is-a-better-way-to-name-the-wrong-question), painting themselves into corners. I could add hundreds of lines of code to a source file without changing how it works, and vice versa I could change one character, and break it completely. To me, adding or changing substitutions do not constitute "not modifying the system", and so I see a contradiction in what you are saying.

Comment: adding any number of character to the source code is "modifying it". Even a space. Even a comment. Unless that number is zero. You might question that constraint, but I can't understand where you find a **contradiction** in my question. A contradiction is a logic derivation from the same set of premises of both a proposition P and its negation ¬P. And regarding the "wrong question", life is such that we often have to face constraints that sound silly. Often those constraints are named "management".

Comment: @Jean-DenisMuys I think this confusion comes from us not quite understanding your exact situation. You have my sympathies, and I wish you luck with your endeavours.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
 my ($first, $rest) = /(.+?)\#\#(.*)/;
```

`//` (or, `m//`) is matching; you don't need to use `s///` for substitution. It returns the matches (here, to `$first`, `$rest`), or you can capture them later using `$1`, `$2`, &c.

Comment: I get the error "Use of uninitialized value $_ in pattern match (m//) at untitled line 9.". In any case, I don't have the option of doing what you suggest. The system I work with only provides regex substitution. My Perl snippet is basically simulating it. I get to input the matching pattern and the substitution pattern.

Comment: Yes, you would have to assign to `$_` or bind to a string with `=~`.
If you *must* use substitutions, use the same expression, but twice. `s/(.+?)\#\#(.*)/$1/`, `s/(.+?)\#\#(.*)/$2/`

Comment: it doesn't seem to work. If I input 'one', then it yields 'one' for the `$rest`, which should be the empty string. This is because $rest doesn't match and thus is not substituted.

Comment: Gotcha, re-reading the question, I'd misunderstood the constraint: you can *only* use s/// expressions, no code, so the patterns @Sodved provided are more useful to you.

Answer (score 0):

You have reversed the quantifiers `?` and `+` in the second regex, it should be:

```
$rest =~ s/(.+?)(##)?(.*)/$3/g;
          ___^^
```

or more concise:

```
$rest =~ s/.+?##(.*)/$1/;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd must match; not substitute:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
while (<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    m{([^#]*?)##(.*)} and print "[$1][$2]\n";
}
__DATA__
''
'one'
'one##two'
'one##two##three'
'one##two words##three'
```

Comment: Wow! I wish I good write Perl this way. And I wish I could also read it. That said, it seems to me this doesn't answer the question.